# Create Xamarin plugin/user control Library

Tags: c#, xamarin, plugins, user-controls, nuget-package

I need to create a Xamarin plugin (something that could be released on Nuget) containing UI and Business Logic related to a private business login process.

**Now my question is: What is the best way to create that ?**

I was thinking to create two separate project in Xamarin that would embed everything, an  iOS class library and an Android class library. Is it possibile to do so ? And, more important for me, is it possibile to include UI in this type of project and design it in XAML ?

The ui should be quite simple, a login form with two text entry and a button but I'd like to use a visual editor to do that.

The real plus, obviously, of the plugin is the business login underneath that will use a custom authentication type.

Comment: Go and have a look at some other libraries on github. You should create a project with whatever you need. This project will be structured just like your xamarin app with a shared, ios and android class library. Perhaps other class libraries if you want to put specific ""business logic"" into it. You then make sure your controls/services are accessible (most people put them in a .abstractions namespace). Then you can turn your project into a private nuget and add it to your project. You should research this on google some more!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create Multiplatform Library project where you can implement platform specific implementation of your Library business logics.

There is a nice tutorial on Microsoft website:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/cross-platform/app-fundamentals/nuget-multiplatform-libraries/single-codebase

To learn more about creating the Nuget package you should go through: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/create-packages/overview-and-workflow